# read json object using javascript and ajax i got error due to CORS policy

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       function ondata(){
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){

            var javaobj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
            document.getElementById('mass').innerHTML=javaobj.name;
          }
         };
         xhttp.open("GET","student.json",true); 
         xhttp.send();
       }


    </script>
    <input type="button"name="name" onclick="ondata()" value="Click"/>
    <div id="mass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i got the error
6hp.html:21 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/ind/ip-simple/student.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Comment: is there a local (dev) server running? Your browser can't request files directly from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me with file structure
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIRXK.png). Try moving json file to the same directory as your html file.

I might be wrong, but browsers restrict the files you can access from your script to those within same directory.

Comment: i got clear the error by run my Ajax code through the tomcat server